# Vue 3 render function no class reactivity

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity, vue-render-function

i need to use hyperscript from vue (**h** function) but i have a problem with conditionnal class.

Here a reproduction link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-albattani-hxk5dd?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Finput.vue%3A14%2C20

in the *input.vue* view I display the props *invalid* (next to the input) and in the input itself I declare conditionnal class

```
:class="{ '--invalid': invalid }"
```

if i start writing in the input the props displayed change as expected, but the conditionnal class is not updated.

Any idea on how to correct this ?

Here my input component

```
    <template>
  <div>
    invalid: {{ invalid }}
    <input
      class="theinput"
      :class="{ '--invalid': invalid }"
      @input="updateValue"
      v-model="value"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
const props = defineProps(["invalid"]);
const value = ref("");
const emit = defineEmits(["update:value"]);

const updateValue = (event: Event) => {
  emit("update:value", (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
};
</script>

<style>
.theinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.--invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

here how i call i with render function

```
    import { h, defineEmits } from "vue";

import theinput from "./input.vue";

const render = (details: any, invalid: any) => {
  const emit = defineEmits(["update:value"]);
  let copy = { ...details };
  copy.invalid = invalid;
  return h(theinput, {
    ...copy,
    "update:value": (value: any) => emit("update:value", value),
  });
};

export { render };
```

and the app.vue

```
    <template>
  <!-- <theinput :invalid="invalid" @update:value="validate" /> -->
  <render-input @update:value="validate"></render-input>
</template>

<script setup>
import theinput from "./components/input.vue";
import { render } from "./components/input.ts";
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from "vue";

let invalid = ref(true);
const validate = (value) => {
  invalid.value = value.length < 3;
  console.log(invalid.value);
  console.log(renderInput.value);
};

onBeforeMount(() => {
  defineComponent();
});
let renderInput = ref(null);
const defineComponent = () => {
  renderInput.value = render({}, invalid);
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

When the invalid change to false the red border would disapear

**EDIT**

I fund the solution,in my component declaration

```
  <div>
invalid: {{ invalid }}
<input
  class="theinput"
  :class="{ '--invalid': invalid }"
  @input="updateValue"
  v-model="value"
/>
```

the `invalid: {{ invalid }}` mustn't have *.value* but the `:class="{ '--invalid': invalid }"` need it. Both are in template so i don't know if its a normal behaviour. I asked on the offical git repo vue.

Comment: I get "_Sandbox not found.  It's likely that the Sandbox you're trying to access doesn't exist or you don't have the required permissions to access it._"  Runnable examples are great, but because of possible access issues and links breaking over time it's always [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=but%20also%20copy%20the%20code%20into%20the%20question%20itself.) to include all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: thanks for the advice, question edited and i edited permission on sandbox

Comment: I can't edit your repro, so I can't try it, but my guess is that in *App.vue*, `invalid` is a Ref<boolean>, same in *input.ts*. However, in *input.vue*, `invalid` is a boolean, so you may have to use `invalid.value` in *input.ts*. This is only a guess but it would be coherent with the observed behaviour, as a ref is always evaluated to true (since it is a non-empty object), but its value can be evaluated to true or false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Billuc but if in *input .ts* I change for invalid.value   
  copy.invalid = invalid.value;              i lost reactivity :s

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense... Have you tried something like [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function#v-model) with props and emits ?

Comment: @Billuc yes but thats not related to my problem, if you look at the gif the property *invalid * (near the input) change to true at false but the css class (for red border), related to the same property,  is not removed.

Comment: Oh yeah mb, I was focusing on the wrong thing.... Have you tried `props.invalid` instead of `invalid` ? I gotta say it is weird that the value is updated and not the style. Is the class still here when invalid == false ?

Answer (score -2):

Using the : syntax for the class binding in the input.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    invalid: {{ invalid }}
    <input
      class="theinput"
      :class="{ '--invalid': invalid }"
      @input="updateValue"
      v-model="value"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, defineProps, defineEmits } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  invalid: boolean;
}>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "update:value", value: string): void;
}>();

const value = ref(props.invalid ? "" : null);

watch(
  () => props.invalid,
  (newValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
      value.value = "";
    }
  }
);

const updateValue = (event: Event) => {
  emit("update:value", (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
};
</script>

<style>
.theinput:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.--invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

In this updated version, we are using the : syntax to bind the class attribute, and we are using the watch function to update the value reactive reference when the invalid prop changes.

Here's the updated render function in the input.ts file:

```
import { h, defineEmits, defineProps } from "vue";

import Theinput from "./input.vue";

const render = (value: any, invalid: any) => {
  const emit = defineEmits<{
    (e: "update:value", value: string): void;
  }>();

  let copy = { ...value };
  copy.invalid = invalid;
  return h(Theinput, {
    value: value,
    invalid: copy,
    "update:value": (v: string
```